# Android, plugin system and reflected classes

Tags: android, class, plugins, reflection

I'm developing an app that will need to have some sort of plugin system.

Is it possible to load classes with reflection on a separate .apk?

Any other ideas are welcome.

EDIT: Solved, thanks everyone. In the end I came up with this:

```
public Object loadPlugin(String packageName, String className) {
    try {
        return (Object) new PathClassLoader(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).applicationInfo.sourceDir, null, getClassLoader()).loadClass(className).getConstructor(new Class[]{ Context.class, IXoneApp.class }).newInstance(new Object[] {this, this.appData()});
    } catch (NameNotFoundException ex) {
        Utils.DebugLog(Utils.TAG_FRAMEWORK, "El módulo " + packageName + " no está instalado");
        return null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Utils.DebugLog(Utils.TAG_FRAMEWORK, "Fallo al invocar el módulo " + packageName + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea how it works or even if but http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html sounds like it could do something like that

Comment: That sounds good, it works. It could be something like this:`DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader("/mnt/sdcard/whatever.apk", "/path/temp", null, getClassLoader());` But what if i want the user to just install the apk? This requires the apk to be on that path.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more specific about "plugin". If you want the ability to add separate features, you may want to have a main .apk and then smaller .apks to implement the plugins. Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm developing a mobile application framework. From the main application, the developer can run some sort of script. I have implemented PDF generation and other stuff in the framework, but these make the .apk huge. With reflection I can build different .apks, one with PDF generation and without it, but I don't want that. What I'd like to accomplish is that if the developer wants to make use of PDF generation, then he'll have to install the PDF plugin.